# Alignment of DIP chips in CircuiTikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

I want to use `circuitikz` to make a breadboard layout.
Preamble:

```latex
\tikzset{
  open socket/.style = {
    circle,
    fill = lightgray,
    inner sep = 1pt
  },
  filled socket/.style = {
    circle,
    fill = black,
    inner sep = 1pt
  }
}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows.meta, backgrounds}
```

So far, I've gotten the grid:

```latex
%% draw breadboard sections
  \foreach \y [evaluate = \y as \line using int(abs(\y))] in {0, ..., -13}{

    % draw line numbers off to the left
    \node [text=gray] at (-9, \y) {\line};
    \node [text=gray] at (9, \y) {\line};

    % draw bus and breadboard grid sockets
    \foreach \lab/\x in {l-/-8, lg/-7, A/-5, B/-4, C/-3, D/-2, E/-1, F/1, G/2, H/3, I/4, J/5, rg/7, r+/8} {
      \coordinate [open socket] (\lab\line) at (\x, \y);
    }

    % draw row connectivity for board proper
    \draw [lightgray, opacity = 0.2, very thick]
      (-5, \y) -- (-1, \y)
      (1, \y)  -- (5, \y);

  }

  % label breadboard columns

  \foreach \lab/\x in {A/-5, B/-4, C/-3, D/-2, E/-1, F/1, G/2, H/3, I/4, J/5} {
    \node [above of = \lab0] {\lab};
  }

  % label buses

  \node [above of=l-0] {V$_{-}$};
  \node [above of=lg0] {GND$_{}$};
  \node [above of=rg0] {GND$_{}$};
  \node [above of=r+0] {V$_{+}$};

  % draw bus connection lines
  \begin{scope} [
      on background layer  % these paths should not interfere with anything else
    ]
    \draw [very thick, red,  opacity = 0.2] (l-0) -- (l-13);
    \draw [very thick, blue, opacity = 0.2] (lg0) -- (lg13);

    \draw [very thick, blue, opacity = 0.2] (rg0) -- (rg13);
    \draw [very thick, red,  opacity = 0.2] (r+0) -- (r+13);
  \end{scope}
```

[image: Bare Breadboard]
Now, I want to position a DIP chip in the middle of the breadboard, and what I've got till now is this:

```latex
\node at (E1) (081) [
                        dipchip,
                        fill = cyan!20!white,
                        circuitikz/multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing = 0.711,
                        circuitikz/multipoles/dipchip/width = 1.03,
                        anchor = pin 1,
                        num pins = 8,
                        hide numbers
                    ] {TL081};

  % and fill its pins with tiny descriptions:

  \node [right, font=\tiny] at (081.bpin 1) {ON1};
  \node [right, font=\tiny] at (081.bpin 2) {IN-};
  \node [right, font=\tiny] at (081.bpin 3) {IN+};
  \node [right, font=\tiny] at (081.bpin 4) {$V_-$};

  \node [left,  font=\tiny] at (081.bpin 5) {ON2};
  \node [left,  font=\tiny] at (081.bpin 6) {OUT};
  \node [left,  font=\tiny] at (081.bpin 7) {$V_+$};
  \node [left,  font=\tiny] at (081.bpin 8) {NC};

  \foreach \i in {1, 2, ..., 8} {
    \node at (081.pin \i) [filled socket] {};
  }
```

which yields:
[image: Chip Breadboard]
The *result* itself is fine; however, it requires that I manually align the chip, which isn't very flexible.  Is there a better way to do this alignment?  Alternatively, is there a spacing method that I can use for the breadboard that will allow the chip spacing to correspond to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with the fact the in `circuititz` all the lenghts are proportional to `bipoles/length` (default 1.4cm); for example:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}
\ctikzset{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing=1}
\ctikzset{multipoles/external pins width=0.5}
\ctikzset{multipoles/dipchip/width=3}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[x=1cm, y=1cm,
    ]
    \draw [cyan, dashed](-4,-4) grid (4,4);
    \draw (-3,3) to[R, *-*] ++(1,0);
    \path (-2,3) node[dipchip, anchor=pin 1, num pins=12]{DIP};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Or you can change the x,y coordinates using the current value of the bipoles length, like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
% \ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}
\makeatletter\newlength{\Rlen}\setlength{\Rlen}{\pgf@circ@Rlen}\makeatother
\ctikzset{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing=1}
\ctikzset{multipoles/external pins width=0.5}
\ctikzset{multipoles/dipchip/width=3}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    x=\Rlen, y=\Rlen,
    ]
    \draw [cyan, dashed](-4,-4) grid[step=\Rlen] (4,4);
    \draw (-3,3) to[R, *-*] ++(1,0);
    \path (-2,3) node[dipchip, anchor=pin 1, num pins=12]{DIP};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

which gives more or less the same result.

Comment: Thanks, Romano!  Sorry for the cross posting, I figured I'd make this more accessible here as well.  The related Github issue is here: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/213

Answer (score 4):

To put out a warning, I modified your code pretty heavily. However, I think it's more versatile now.

I changed the following aspects:

- The amount of rows is now a parameter
- The size of the middle gap is now a parameter
- The text size is now a parameter
- Added explanation about scaling

I created this new breadboard command. It's still somewhat similar to yours. Do not be scared by the many #2s, this is just the middle gap. I also combined some of your drawing logic to avoid unnecessary iterations. You can also take it as a black box and be fine but do note that I changed how the breadboard looks slightly and you may want to change this back.

```latex
\newcommand{\breadboard}[3]{%
    \foreach \y in {1, ..., #1}{

            % Draw line numbers
            \node [text=gray] at (-2, -\y) {#3\y};
            \node [text=gray] at (12+#2, -\y) {#3\y};

            % Draw the pins
            \foreach \x in {-1, ..., 5, 5+#2, 6+#2, 7+#2, 8+#2, 9+#2, 10+#2, 11+#2}{
                    \fill[lightgray, radius=3pt] (\x,-\y) circle;
                }

            % Draw horizontal lines
            \draw [lightgray, opacity = 0.2, very thick] (1,-\y) -- (5, -\y);
            \draw [lightgray, opacity = 0.2, very thick] (5+#2,-\y) -- (9+#2, -\y);

        }

    % Draw labels
    \foreach \label/\x in {\color{red}+/-1, \color{blue}-/0, A/1, B/2, C/3, D/4, E/5, F/5+#2, G/6+#2, H/7+#2, I/8+#2, J/9+#2, \color{red}+/10+#2, \color{blue}-/11+#2}{
            \node at (\x, 0) {#3\label};
        }

    % draw bus connection lines
    \draw [very thick, red,  opacity = 0.2] (-1,-1) -- (-1,-#1);
    \draw [very thick, blue, opacity = 0.2] (0,-1) -- (0,-#1);
    \draw [very thick, red, opacity = 0.2] (10+#2,-1) -- (10+#2,-#1);
    \draw [very thick, blue,  opacity = 0.2] (11+#2,-1) -- (11+#2,-#1);

    % Optional border
    \draw [black, very thick] (-2.5,1) -- (-2.5,-#1-0.5) -- (12.5+#2,-#1-0.5) -- (12.5+#2,1) -- cycle;
}
```

Lets define some constants provided by the other great answer

```latex
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}
\ctikzset{multipoles/dipchip/pin spacing=1}
\ctikzset{multipoles/external pins width=0.5}
\ctikzset{multipoles/dipchip/width=1}
```

We can now call our breadboard command where the first argument is the number of columns, the second is the width of the middle gap in terms of whole pin distances and the third argument is just something to be put before any text. You can use this to change font, fontsize, color, etc

```latex
\begin{circuitikz}[
    ]
    \breadboard{10}{2}{\huge}

    \node [
        dipchip,
        anchor=pin 1,
        fill = cyan!20!white,
        num pins = 8,
        hide numbers
    ] at (5,-2) {TL081};


\end{circuitikz}
\vspace{20pt}
```

[image: An Image showing the rendered breadboard]

Not very pretty this way right? However, if we make the board longer and change the fontsize it looks great. At least in my opinion. But to make the breadboard bigger we need to scale our image down. Note that we do not only scale the tikzpicture but we also need to scale the chip separately. When scaling down, we notice our fontsize stays big. This is bad but fortunately the third parameter lets us easily deal with that problem. Note how we set the fontsize to \small instead of previous \huge

```latex
\begin{circuitikz}[
        scale=0.5
    ]
    \breadboard{30}{2}{\small}

    \node [
        dipchip,
        circuitikz/chips/scale=0.5,
        anchor=pin 1,
        fill = cyan!20!white,
        num pins = 8,
        hide numbers
    ] at (5,-2) {TL081};


\end{circuitikz}
\vspace{20pt}
```

[image: An Image showing the rendered breadboard]

But we can even do better than this!!! Sometimes your chips get pretty big and you want to write a description of every pin but the space is too scarce. Using the first parameter we can change the middle gap so our chips can be very wide and contain lots of useful text. Notice how we also overwrote the chipwidth!

```latex
\begin{circuitikz}[
        scale=0.5
    ]
    \breadboard{30}{6}{\small}

    \node [
        dipchip,
        circuitikz/chips/scale=0.5,
        circuitikz/multipoles/dipchip/width=5,
        anchor=pin 1,
        fill = cyan!20!white,
        num pins = 8,
        hide numbers
    ] at (5,-2) {TL081};


\end{circuitikz}
\vspace{20pt}
```

[image: An Image showing the rendered breadboard]