# how do I change the dipchip origin in circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Is there a way to change the origin of a DipChip like there is with Logic ports?

In logic ports you just write `\ctikzset{logic ports origin=(anchor where your center will be)}`

And thats it!

How do I do that with Dipchips?

Comment: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf--- 
            page 100 and 104

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493239/alignment-of-dip-chips-in-circuitikz/49325

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514490/pgf-tikz-circuitikz-define-a-new-component/514514#514514

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521798/custom-integrated-circuits-with-circuitikz

Comment: This seems an XY question... Why do you want to change the centerpoint? You can position the element using any one of the anchors of the node, like `node[dipchip, anchor=west]... ` - - - the logic port thing is there only for backward compatibility.

Comment: Also, notice that you can't use an arbitrary node for `logic ports origin`, just `center` or `legacy`...